# How do I set up a linear program in COIN-OR Clp?

Tags: c++, linear-programming, coin-or-cbc, coin-or-clp

I'm using COIN-OR Clp, and I need to define my linear problem in C++. I can construct my problem in terms of a matrix and a constraint vector, but I don't understand the format that Clp needs this information in. How do I structure a CoinPackedMatrix or a CoinBigIndex, etc., to pass to ClpSimplex via ClpSimplex.loadProblem()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2320035/sascha

Comment: You can use one of the `LoadProblem` methods.